# How to target a single div in a loop with jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, loops

I have this loop here that shows post data from a WordPress blog -

```
<?php foreach ( $product_posts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
<div class="card-container">
    <div class="card-image">
        <figure>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
        </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-card-text">
        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <p><?php the_excerpt() ?></p>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endforeach; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Using this jQuery function -

```
$(".card-container").mouseenter(function () {
  $(".gallery-card-text").show();
  $(".card-image").hide();
});
```

It targets everything in the loop, so if you hover over 1 post it hides the image on all of them. I want to show/hide each div in the loop individually on mouse enter.

How can I do this?

Comment: why even use JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the elements in the element you hovered.

```
$(".card-container").mouseenter(function () {
  var card = $(this);
  card.find(".gallery-card-text").show();
  car.find(".card-image").hide();
});
```

but why even use JavaScript when simple CSS can do it?

```
.card-container .gallery-card-text { display: none;} 
.card-container:hover .gallery-card-text { display: block;} 
.card-container .card-image { display: block;}
.card-container:hover .card-image { display: none;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify which `.gallery-card-text` you want to show and which `.card-image` you want to hide.

When using jQuery's events, `this` is bound to the element that you set the trigger on, you can use this element as the "scope" to determine which elements you want to hide

```js
 $(".card-container").mouseenter(function () {
    var $this = $(this); // this = current .card-container
    
    // use .find() to get the elements within $this
    $this.find(".gallery-card-text").show();
    $this.find(".card-image").hide();
  });
```

**ES6**

```js
$(".card-container")
    .mouseenter((event) => {
         // event.currentTarget = current .card-container
        let $this = $(event.currentTarget);

        // use .find() to get the elements within $this
        $this.find(".gallery-card-text").show();
        $this.find(".card-image").hide();
    });
```